# Available tools & techniques for locating sections of interest in a binary executable

Tags: disassembly, tools, executable

If I'm trying to figure out how a program accomplishes a certain task or how it works with an unknown data structure or format, what techniques and tools can I employ to quickly and efficiently locate the binary sections of interest to start answering those questions?

As a concrete example, say I'm trying to figure out how a game client calculates and validates a checksum. I've observed the following properties without any initial disassembly:

- That checksum is used to validate whether an ingame item stats is legit or not.
- The checksum is being performed on the client-side.
- It is a 2-byte checksum.

What I've done is to feed in a particular item with my own checksum signature so it could be identified in memory when I disassemble it. Once I got the location in memory I set a memory breakpoint on it whenever it gets accessed. From there I just backtraced where the control flow was coming from.

While it took a long while with a lot of trial-and-error I was eventually able to locate the code section responsible for this checksum calculation and successfully recreated a C-program that does this.

Another problem with the approach I used is that there could be a lot of 'false positives'. That memory location I'm monitoring could be accessed by various parts of the program that has nothing to do with the checksum calculation -- thus where the trial-and-error comes in.

The focus of asking this question is, **is there an easier way to go about this?** What if I wanted to identify key data structures being used by the program? What about identifying functions and calculations that aren't as 'easily observable'? Not all values being used in the program can be easily isolated using a memory scanner like cheat-engine.

Answer (score 4):

It's much easier and reliable IMO to identify a checksum algorithm than determining it by whiteboxing (ie, comparing buffer and its checksum), except if the checksum is trivial, which you might quickly find out by altering the last byte of data.

either:

- set a memory read breakpoint on the part of the data that is likely to be the checksum value (the end?) as soon as possible, then execute further
- scroll through each function in IDA to flag those that are likely to be checksums - complex ones have very different kind of ASM usually.

  - if none, maybe the checksum is inlined and a simple one - you might want to search for shift/xor/rol sequences

Comment: Plugins like findcrypt and similar can help identify when well known crypto hashes are being used, although that's clearly not the case in greatwolf's target.

Comment: You're right, but well known hashes are easy to spot manually IMHO - better have also a generic methodology - if there is any obfuscation, findcrypt would also fail.